# Different background color between pressed down and released with xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-button

Edit:

To make it really clear what I am looking for, here is exactly what I want.

When a user is holding down the button (finger still on screen), I want it to show one color (eg the default Android translucent ripple effect), then, depending on whether the user completes the click, (if they lift their finger while it is on the button, Android will register that as a click, if they move their finger outside of the bounds of the button and THEN lift their finger, Android will not register that as a click) I want it to show different colors.

I am looking for the xml code that will make a button do this.

When held down, show the default Android ripple effect (easy), if the user completes the click, show a green ripple effect to confirm. If the user does not complete the click, the ripple from the user holding down the button should fade back out.

So far, none of the xml solutions here or on the other questions does this. So I am probably going to have to manually do this within the onTouchListener.

======================================================================

I am trying to create a ripple effect state list drawable for my button and I can't figure out how to have it so that when my button is being held down, the ripple is one color, then if the user completes the button press by releasing their finger on the button, the ripple is another color.

Right now, my ripple color is the same when pressed down and when the button press is released.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enterFadeDuration="200" android:exitFadeDuration="200">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/md_teal_500" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Is there any way to do this using a state list drawable xml or will I have to manually do this with a touch listener?

Comment: what do you want another way or any working way ?

Answer (score 3):

Create below xml files in the drawable folder.
buttonnorml.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid
        android:width="2px"
        android:color="@color/green" />
</shape>
```

buttonselected.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid
        android:width="5px"
        android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```

buttonclickeffect.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonselected" android:state_pressed="true" /><!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonnorml" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Use it as background of button:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonclickeffect"
        android:text="sample" />
```

Comment: @Ritz Malheur Mark it as answer if it helped you

Comment: Happily gave you 2 for this answer!!!  I am new to Android, and couldn't find anything useful on SO 3 weeks ago and had to scrub the ticket.  Now it's fixed!!!  Ideas for doing the same thing with text color?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I want. With your method, the button is red when there is no interaction. Then when you hold your finger down on the button, it becomes green. I am going to clarify what I am looking for in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same in code using:

```
int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
TypedArray typedArray = getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
int backgroundResource = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);
myView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);
```

f you want to customize the ripple effect into a view, you need to create a new XML file, inside the drawable directory.

Here are few examples:

**Example 1**: An unbounded ripple

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ffff0000" />
```

**Example 2:** Ripple with mask and background color

```
<ripple android:color="#7777777"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="#ffff00" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
</ripple>
```

**Example 3:** Ripple on top a drawable resource

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ff0000ff">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable" />
</ripple>
```

**Usage:** To attach your ripple xml file to any view, set it as background as following: assuming your ripple file is named my_ripple.xml.

```
<View 
    android:id="@+id/myViewId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_ripple" />
```

Comment: I already know how to use drawables. What I want is to have a different ripple color between a button/view being pressed down and held vs when released. I am wondering if there is a way to do this using only state list drawables and not having to do it manually with a touch listener.